# WhatsApp Business API send media template error

Tags: laravel, whatsapp, whatsapi

I have created a media template in what's app business API. But I cannot send the template message where the media file is attached in the header.

My media template object.

```
{
    "name": "business_five",
    "components": [
        {
            "type": "HEADER",
            "format": "IMAGE",
            "example": {
                "header_handle": [
                    "https://scontent.whatsapp.net/v/t61.29466-34/323170987_1239753446972881_6537482729362490175_n.jpg?ccb=1-7&_nc_sid=57045b&_nc_ohc=24dzgQb3Xc8AX9Nllk_&_nc_ht=scontent.whatsapp.net&edm=AH51TzQEAAAA&oh=01_AdRx0hLfUqy4nKvgGz1cf23Em9ElezWo1o4UPrfwPGeVgg&oe=64336E79"
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "BODY",
            "text": "Dear All,\nWishing you ramadan mubarak."
        }
    ],
    "language": "en_US",
    "status": "APPROVED",
    "category": "MARKETING",
    "id": "1235769690704590"
}
```

When I'm sending this template message to others using the API `https://graph.facebook.com/{{version}}/{{phone_number_id}}/messages`
it's showing the error :

> (#132012) Parameter format does not match format in the created template

Can anyone help me with how can I send a media template message? My post field was

```
$message = [
    "messaging_product" => "whatsapp",
    "to" => "8801704158504",
    "type" => "template",
    "template" => [
        "name" => $template->name,
        "language" => [
            "code" => $template->language
        ],
        "components" => [
            [
                "type" => "header",
                "parameters" => [
                    'type' => 'image',
                    'image' => [
                        'link' => 'https://imgur.com/a/wu3BP6R'
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You are missing the bracket after `parameters` property,
- Second, there is an issue with the media URL also, you need to pass the exact destination of the image instead of the routing path like it should have an extension `.jpeg/.png`

```
"parameters" => [
  [
    'type' => 'image',
    'image' => [
      'link' => 'https://imagepath/image-name.jpeg' // or .png
    ]
  ]
]
```